# Guzzle didn't set cookies for request from Codeception

Tags: php, unit-testing, cookies, guzzle, codeception

I'm using for test my API (unit test in this case) Codeception. When I trying to set some cookies with `GET` request, I have noticed, that global variable $_COOKIE is empty (I use `var_dump($_COOKIE)` in index.php of my project (Kohana framework)). Here is the part of code of my test:

```
$this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => Fixtures::get('front_url') . '/api/some_segmint_1/',
        'cookies' => true,
    ]);

$cookieJar = CookieJar::fromArray([
        'name_of_cookie' => 'some_value',
    ], 'my_domain.loc');

$res = $this->client->request('GET', 'some_segmint_2', ['cookies' => $cookieJar]);
var_dump($res);
```

Running test in terminal:

```
php vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run tests/unit/Controller/Api/MyTest.php
```

I got just empty array. Why could this happen?
`PHP 5.6`, `guzzlehttp/guzzle v6.3.0`, `codeception/codeception v2.3.6`

Comment: Does domain of front_url match domain of the cookie (my_domain.loc)?

Comment: Yes, they match.